# Why When I Convert a 22+ Digit Decimal Number To Hexadecimal The Result is 10?

Tags: javascript

So I wrote a code that converts from decimal to hexadecimal and when i entered a 22 digit number or more the result is always 20 can someone explain why is this happening? here is the code, i went to online sites to convert such a number and it works there but why not with me?:

```js
function convert(x) {
    x = parseFloat(x);
    var mod = 0;
    var sum = "";
    var FinalSum = "";
    var y;
    var str;
    var slpha;
    var beta;
    while (x !== 0) {
      mod = x % 16;
      if (mod == 10) {
        sum += "a";
      } else if (mod == 11) {
        sum += "b";
      } else if (mod == 12) {
        sum += "c";
      } else if (mod == 13) {
        sum += "d"
      } else if (mod == 14) {
        sum += "e";
      } else if (mod == 15) {
        sum += "f";
      } else {
        sum += mod;
      }
      x = parseInt(x / 16);
    } //while loop end.

    /* everything is right 
    till now but you have to
    deal with the reverse issue */
    str = sum;
    alpha = sum.length - 1;
    beta = alpha + 1;
    while (alpha !== -1) {

      FinalSum += str.slice(alpha, beta);
      beta--;
      alpha--;

    } //while loop end.     

    console.log(FinalSum);
  }
convert(1212312313123123123456);
```

Comment: Probably bumping up against the largest possible number in JS.

Comment: I made a snippet, please change it to reflect your issue

Comment: @ScottMarcus The largest number in JavaScript is represented as `Infinity`, and would result in an infinite loop here (since math operations on both `Infinity` and `NaN` result in `NaN`, the loop will not terminate).

Comment: @OP This functionality is built-in to JavaScript; you can just do `(1212312313123123123456).toString(16)`.  You can invoke `toString(16)` like this on any number value.

Comment: @mplungjan well it worked for 22 digits but i tried 24+ digits and the result would be 70

Comment: @cdhowie The largest number in JavaScript **+1* is displayed as `Infinity`, not the largest number.

Comment: @cdhowie wow this method save alot of effort. However if you convert a very large number it will keep adding zeros and more zeros, i even went on to a site to check if that happens and it did well i guess there is nothing to do about.